# Why does conditional formatting work on iris data frame with formattable package, but not when columns are of different types as in this example?

Tags: r, conditional-formatting, formattable

I am trying to format the numeric columns of a data frame where the columns types include dates, characters, and doubles (i.e., numeric).

When I use the formattable package on a data frame like iris, I get the expected results.  However, when I use this on my data frame, I don't get the expected results (numbers are not correctly formatted based on value).

Here is a **reproducible example** with simple dummy data:

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(formattable)


# Create formattable function to conditionally format numbers.  If > 5, make green...
sign_formatter <- formatter("span", 
                            style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x > 5, "green", 
                                                             ifelse(x < 5, "red", "black")
                            )
                            )
)



# Formats as expected on iris data frame, other than makes Species column green (and maybe not if the 5.0 in iris is exactly 5, then this should format with the color black):

formattable(iris, list(~ sign_formatter))
```

[image: iris]

```
# Create data frame to replicate type of data frame I have
my_class = LETTERS[1:3]
my_dates = seq(as.Date("2019/01/01"), by = "day", length.out = 3)
my_nums1 = c(1, 5, 10)
my_nums_2 = c(-5, 0, 7)

my_df <- data.frame(my_class, my_dates, my_nums1, my_nums_2)


# Does not format as expected
formattable(my_df, list(~ sign_formatter))
```

[image: my_df]

```
   # Formats correctly if I select numeric columns only, but of course I lose the other columns given use of select_if:

formattable(my_df %>%
              select_if(., is.numeric), list(~ sign_formatter))
```

[image: my_numeric]

**Question:**  Why does formattable not work on the example data frame, and how can I make it work in this case without individually specifying the formatting of each column (or without returning only the numeric columns when using select_if)?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't know why someone would draw your conclusion given both data frames in this example are reproducible (iris, my_df).   Just use str(iris) and str(my_df) to get the structure.  The picture was to show the formatting output.

Comment: It’s my allergic reaction to screenshot in SO. I would have copied output from dput() to my console. I agree that my initial reaction was wrong. The print output of dataframes is often misleading.

Comment: No worries, I understand the initial reaction.  I appreciate you looking at the question.

Comment: If I try: `formattable(my_df, list(area(,my_nums1) ~ sign_formatter))` i get expected results. So far I have not figured out the difference in you examples.

Comment: Using your area approach, if I try:  `numeric_cols <- colnames(my_df[,sapply(my_df, is.numeric)])` and `formattable(my_df, list(area(, numeric_cols) ~ sign_formatter))`  then I can format the data frames in a scalable way.